# Battery Charge Suddenly Drops from 54 % to 7 %

Tags: battery, lenovo-laptop

I own a Lenovo B 570 series laptop. The laptop and battery being an year old lasts only 1 hour. But the strange thing is that, when the charge comes down to 54 % it drops to 7 %(critical battery level) in a moment.

I have windows 8 pro 32 bit installed.

Please suggest some solution (other than replacing the battery).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Battery charge suddenly drops from about 25% to 6%](http://superuser.com/questions/155395/battery-charge-suddenly-drops-from-about-25-to-6) also see [Laptop Battery does not show true charging level](http://superuser.com/questions/47189/laptop-battery-does-not-show-true-charging-level)

Comment: You have a weak cell. Pony up and buy a new quality manufactured pack. Magic doesn't work on batteries, nothing else to suggest even if you don't want to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this sounds normal for a battery in poor condition where the voltage drops much faster than Windows was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

This happens with time, I have a 7 year old toshiba laptop and his battery only lasts 10 min max. The  batteries only last 2 years (aprox)